# Index error in one editor but works in pycharm

Tags: python, list

So I'm doing py.checkio.org which is a coding game for python. My task is to reorder elements in a list. I got it working in pycharm but when i copy my solution to checkios editor I get

```
IndexError: list index out of range
 <listcomp>, 11
 replace_first, 11
```

Here's my code

```
from typing import Iterable


def replace_first(items: list) -> Iterable:
    lastdigit=len(items)
    if len(items) == 1:
        return items
    elif len(items) == 0:
        return items
    myorder = [1,2,3,0]
    items=[items[i] for i in myorder]
    return items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Example:")
    print(list(replace_first([1, 2, 3, 4])))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert list(replace_first([1, 2, 3, 4])) == [2, 3, 4, 1]
    assert list(replace_first([1])) == [1]
    assert list(replace_first([])) == []
```

Any idea why?

The code is not elegant in any way but I don't see why I get a index error in one editor but not the other.

Comment: Not related to answer but just a suggestion. You can write the code more clearly. See it      lastdigit=len(items)
    if len(items) == 1:
        return items
    elif len(items) == 0:
        return items       when you've made a variable named lastdigit why don't use it everywhere instead of len function. Also why both if elif if the code inside them is same. Why not 'or'  lastdigit=len(items)
    if lastdigit <= 1: # len can't go below 0.
        return items     it's not the answer but things like these makes code look better.

Comment: Providing the list passed to *replace_first()* has at least 4 elements and *myorder* is as shown in the question then you will **not** get an index error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the code as shown will **not** induce IndexError. Furthermore, the implementation is overly complex and could be just:

```
def replace_first(items: list) -> Iterable:
  return items[1:] + items[:1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
from typing import Union


def change_list_order(items: list, myorder: list) -> Union[list, str]:
    if len(items) <= 1:
        return items
    if len(items) != len(myorder):
        return f"items and myorder lists must have identical qty of elements"
    else:
        items=[items[i] for i in myorder]
        return items
    
print("Example:")
print(change_list_order([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0]))

# These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
assert change_list_order([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0]) == [2, 3, 4, 1]
assert change_list_order([1], [0]) == [1]
assert change_list_order([], [0]) == []
assert change_list_order([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 0, 5]) == "items and myorder lists must have identical qty of elements"
```

Answer (score -1):

Never used assert, not sure about it's output, besides that, your second and third assert tried to reorder 1 item and 0 item with 4 indices. Maybe you can change myorder from `myorder = [1, 2, 3, 4]` to `myorder = [1, 2, 3, 4][:len(item)]`

Comment: my bad, didn't see that you do check the length